# Find out what #define statements conflict between .h files

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2013, boost-preprocessor

I'm in VS2013, C++ console applications.  I'm having a problem integrating boost into a large framework.  If I try integrating them in a blank console application, they work fine.  Once I include the "root" .h file of the framework (that includes "many" other .h files in the bargain), it breaks.  These .h files are "polluting" the boost ones (and anything included after, with mixed results, and no, I can't just include boost ones first, that's not always an option unfortunately).  I've found at least one root-level #define that interfered and caused a compile error, but I can't find some of the other conflicts that are causing run-time problems.

Specifically, my problem is this: how do I tell what symbols have been defined by .h files?  And hopefully, which ones are then conflicting later?  I tried googling, but couldn't find a tool for doing this.

Or is there some other method which can "isolate" them (my problem .h files), and yet still have them link correctly to the functions they're calling in other .dlls?

Comment: May be some static code analysis tool (like PVS-Studio) can help you. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Would generation of pre-compiled headers give this info? not sure what the format of .pch file is in this case, but if its text based perhaps you can then perform a diff between output

Comment: @PetrPervukhin - Yes that's kind of what I thought, but never having used any tools like that, I was hoping for a more concrete recommendation, and/or how to configure such a tool to get that output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `g++ -E` as a static code checking tool (without changing your toolset). It is able to tell you when something is *redefined* but not when a `#define` is used as another name (it would have no way to tell whether it was a real substitution or not).

If that's not the source of your problem then you may need to take a more holistic approach: Start changing your project's `#define` use to other constructs such as const and short functions. This will then allow the compiler to either resolve differences by overloading or complain that there are conflicts.

Comment: As I said in my first line, using Visual Studio.  Not-optional to switch to gcc (this is for work).  And it's a "not small" framework that I'm working with here initially, so switching things is a matter of thousands (if not 10s of thousands) of lines of work.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson I updated my answer but I was just saying to use g++ as a static code checking tool (precompile only), not changing your tool chain.

Answer (score 0):

Including same header file again might have caused the problem,you can create a symbol for each header file so that if that header file is already included in some other header file it shouldn't be included.

```
#ifndef
#define __header_file_name_H
.....some code
#endif
```